# How do I read and write CSV files?

Tags: python, csv

How do I read the following CSV file?

```
1,"A towel,",1.0
42," it says, ",2.0
1337,is about the most ,-1
0,massively useful thing ,123
-2,an interstellar hitchhiker can have.,3
```

---

How do I write the following `data` to a CSV file?

```
data = [
    (1, "A towel,", 1.0),
    (42, " it says, ", 2.0),
    (1337, "is about the most ", -1),
    (0, "massively useful thing ", 123),
    (-2, "an interstellar hitchhiker can have.", 3),
]
```

Comment: This is intended to be a [canonical question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291994/562769) as I just found a lot of duplicates which frame the question differently, but are essentially this question.

Comment: Examples for dupes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788521/reading-a-csv-file-using-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26903304/reading-data-from-a-csv-file-in-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593318/how-to-read-a-csv-file-with-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662571/python-import-csv-to-list http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34568774/reading-a-csv-file-using-python-3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725020/read-csv-file-from-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283799/how-to-read-a-csv-file-from-a-url-python ...

Comment: See also: [Creating a dictionary from a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091387/creating-a-dictionary-from-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Here are some minimal complete examples how to read CSV files and how to write CSV files with Python.

### Pure Python:

```
import csv

# Define data
data = [
    (1, "A towel,", 1.0),
    (42, " it says, ", 2.0),
    (1337, "is about the most ", -1),
    (0, "massively useful thing ", 123),
    (-2, "an interstellar hitchhiker can have.", 3),
]

# Write CSV file
with open("test.csv", "wt") as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=",")
    # writer.writerow(["your", "header", "foo"])  # write header
    writer.writerows(data)

# Read CSV file
with open("test.csv") as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=",", quotechar='"')
    # next(reader, None)  # skip the headers
    data_read = [row for row in reader]

print(data_read)
```

After that, the contents of `data_read` are

```
[['1', 'A towel,', '1.0'],
 ['42', ' it says, ', '2.0'],
 ['1337', 'is about the most ', '-1'],
 ['0', 'massively useful thing ', '123'],
 ['-2', 'an interstellar hitchhiker can have.', '3']]
```

Please note that CSV reads only strings. You need to convert to the column types manually.

A Python 2+3 version was here before ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41585079/27)), but [Python 2 support is dropped](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/). Removing the Python 2 stuff massively simplified this answer.

### Related

- [How do I write data into csv format as string (not file)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9157314/562769)
- [How can I use io.StringIO() with the csv module?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13120127/562769): This is interesting if you want to serve a CSV on-the-fly with Flask, without actually storing the CSV on the server.

### mpu

Have a look at my utility package [`mpu`](https://github.com/MartinThoma/mpu) for a super simple and easy to remember one:

```
import mpu.io
data = mpu.io.read('example.csv', delimiter=',', quotechar='"', skiprows=None)
mpu.io.write('example.csv', data)
```

### Pandas

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the CSV into a pandas data frame (df)
#   With a df you can do many things
#   most important: visualize data with Seaborn
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', sep=',')
print(df)

# Or export it in many ways, e.g. a list of tuples
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]

# or export it as a list of dicts
dicts = df.to_dict().values()
```

See [`read_csv` docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for more information. Please note that pandas automatically infers if there is a header line, but you can set it manually, too.

If you haven't heard of [Seaborn](http://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html), I recommend having a look at it.

### Other

Reading CSV files is supported by a bunch of other libraries, for example:

- [`dask.dataframe.read_csv`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_csv)
- [`spark.read.csv`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv.html)

### Created CSV file

```
1,"A towel,",1.0
42," it says, ",2.0
1337,is about the most ,-1
0,massively useful thing ,123
-2,an interstellar hitchhiker can have.,3
```

### Common file endings

`.csv`

### Working with the data

After reading the CSV file to a list of tuples / dicts or a Pandas dataframe, it is simply working with this kind of data. Nothing CSV specific.

### Alternatives

- JSON: Nice for writing human-readable data; VERY commonly used ([read & write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37795053/562769))
- CSV: Super simple format ([read & write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41585079/562769))
- YAML: Nice to read, similar to JSON ([read & write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42054860/562769))
- pickle: A Python serialization format ([read & write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33245595/562769))
- [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/) ([Python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/msgpack-python)): More compact representation ([read & write](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43442194/562769))
- [HDF5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Data_Format) ([Python package](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/quick.html)): Nice for matrices ([read & write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41586571/562769))
- XML: exists too *sigh* ([read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1912483/562769) & [write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3605831/562769))

For your application, the following might be important:

- Support by other programming languages
- Reading / writing performance
- Compactness (file size)

See also: [Comparison of data serialization formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats)

In case you are rather looking for a way to make configuration files, you might want to read my short article [Configuration files in Python](https://martin-thoma.com/configuration-files-in-python/)

Comment: @icedwater This is a possibility. However, I prefer Pandas: (1) It automatically deals with headers (2) it loads the file directly from the path and does not expect a file pointer (3) it has better "export" options (like the dict export - yes, you can do that with CSV, too. But Pandas is simpler). But feel free to post a solution with does not need Pandas :-)

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering because you used `csv` for writing. I would prefer `csv` or `pandas` for both, and `csv` over `pandas` because it is more likely to already be there.

Comment: @icedwater Ok, I've added a pure `csv` solution (which is now also consistent in structure with my other answers to the other file formats like YAML and JSON)

Comment: For Python 3, you should *always* open CSV files with `newline=""` as per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) — so I think you should change this answer to Your "canonical" question accordingly.

Comment: For small files the time for importing the `pandas` package can be larger than running the complete pure Python solution. In my case the threshold was at about 50 MB.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with CSV data and want a solution with a smaller footprint than `pandas`, you can try my package, [littletable](https://pypi.org/project/littletable/). Can be pip-installed, or just dropped in as a single .py file with your own code, so very portable and suitable for serverless apps.

Reading CSV data is as simple as calling `csv_import`:

```
data = """\
1,"A towel,",1.0
42," it says, ",2.0
1337,is about the most ,-1
0,massively useful thing ,123
-2,an interstellar hitchhiker can have.,3"""

import littletable as lt
tbl = lt.Table().csv_import(data, fieldnames="number1,words,number2".split(','))
tbl.present()
```

Prints:

```
  Number1   Words                                  Number2  
 ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── 
  1         A towel,                               1.0      
  42         it says,                              2.0      
  1337      is about the most                      -1       
  0         massively useful thing                 123      
  -2        an interstellar hitchhiker can have.   3
```

(`littletable` uses the [rich](https://pypi.org/project/rich/) module for presenting Tables.)

`littletable` doesn't automatically try to convert numeric data, so a numeric transform function is needed for the numeric columns.

```
def get_numeric(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            return float(s)
        except ValueError:
            return s

tbl = lt.Table().csv_import(
    data,
    fieldnames="number1,words,number2".split(','),
    transforms={}.fromkeys("number1 number2".split(), get_numeric)
)
tbl.present()
```

This gives:

```
  Number1   Words                                  Number2  
 ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── 
        1   A towel,                                   1.0  
       42    it says,                                  2.0  
     1337   is about the most                           -1  
        0   massively useful thing                     123  
       -2   an interstellar hitchhiker can have.         3
```

The numeric columns are right-justified instead of left-justified.

`littletable` also has other ORM-ish features, such as indexing, joining, pivoting, and full-text search. Here is a table of statistics on the numeric columns:

```
tbl.stats("number1 number2".split()).present()

  Name       Mean   Min    Max   Variance              Std_Dev   Count   Missing  
 ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── 
  number1   275.6    -2   1337   352390.3    593.6247130974249       5         0  
  number2    25.6    -1    123     2966.8   54.468339427597755       5         0
```

or transposed:

```
tbl.stats("number1 number2".split(), by_field=False).present()

  Stat                 Number1              Number2 
 ─────────────────────────────────────────────────── 
  mean                   275.6                 25.6
  min                       -2                   -1
  max                     1337                  123
  variance            352390.3               2966.8
  std_dev    593.6247130974249   54.468339427597755
  count                      5                    5
  missing                    0                    0
```

Other formats can be output too, such as Markdown:

```
print(tbl.stats("number1 number2".split(), by_field=False).as_markdown())

| stat | number1 | number2 |
|---|---:|---:|
| mean | 275.6 | 25.6 |
| min | -2 | -1 |
| max | 1337 | 123 |
| variance | 352390.3 | 2966.8 |
| std_dev | 593.6247130974249 | 54.468339427597755 |
| count | 5 | 5 |
| missing | 0 | 0 |
```

Which would render from Markdown as

| stat | number1 | number2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mean | 275.6 | 25.6 |
| min | -2 | -1 |
| max | 1337 | 123 |
| variance | 352390.3 | 2966.8 |
| std_dev | 593.6247130974249 | 54.468339427597755 |
| count | 5 | 5 |
| missing | 0 | 0 |

Lastly, here is a text search on the words for any entry with the word "hitchhiker":

```
tbl.create_search_index("words")
for match in tbl.search.words("hitchhiker"):
    print(match)
```

Prints:

```
   namespace(number1=-2, words='an interstellar hitchhiker can have.', number2=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Writing a CSV file

First you need to import csv

For example:

```
import csv

with open('eggs.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                        quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

Answer (score 1):

If needed- read a csv file without using the csv module:

```
rows = []
with open('test.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        # strip whitespace
        line = line.strip()
        # separate the columns
        line = line.split(',')
        # save the line for use later
        rows.append(line)
```

Comment: Nice, quick and dirty solution, for CSV's that do not have quoted values. Without too much further trouble, you could read the first line first (the one with the column names), split it on commas, and then append `dict(zip(headers, line))` to get a nice collection of labeled data.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
with open(fileLocation+'example.csv',newline='') as File: #the csv file is stored in a File object

    reader=csv.reader(File)       #csv.reader is used to read a file
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: While this snippet may be a valid answer, some explanation would be helpful.

Comment: Not sure what this adds over the existing answer

Answer (score 0):

**To read a csv file using Pandas**

```
use pd.read_csv("D:\\sample.csv")

using only python :

fopen=open("D:\\sample.csv","r") 

print(fopen.read())
```

**To create and write into a csv file**

The below example demonstrate creating and writing a csv file. to make a dynamic file writer we need to import a package import csv, then need to create an instance of the file with file reference Ex:

```
with open("D:\sample.csv","w",newline="") as file_writer
```

Here if the file does not exist with the mentioned file directory then python will create a same file in the specified directory, and `w` represents write, if you want to read a file then replace `w` with `r` or to append to existing file then `a`.

`newline=""` specifies that it removes an extra empty row for every time you create row so to eliminate empty row we use `newline=""`, create some field names(column names) using list like:

```
fields=["Names","Age","Class"]
```

Then apply to writer instance like:

```
writer=csv.DictWriter(file_writer,fieldnames=fields)
```

Here using Dictionary writer and assigning column names, to write column names to csv we use `writer.writeheader()` and to write values we use `writer.writerow({"Names":"John","Age":20,"Class":"12A"})` ,while writing file values must be passed using dictionary method , here the key is column name and value is your respective key value.

Import csv:

```
with open("D:\sample.csv","w",newline="") as file_writer:

fields=["Names","Age","Class"]

writer=csv.DictWriter(file_writer,fieldnames=fields)

writer.writeheader()

writer.writerow({"Names":"John","Age":21,"Class":"12A"})
```

Comment: Your understanding of what `newline=""` does is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a question asking something similar. So, to keep everything in one place, here are my 2 cents for a very quick & dirty solution.

This code is meant to read from one CSV file and write to another. The format of the output row is fixed, I could have used csv.write with the correct delimiter, but in this case I would have to do extra work to specify the blanks. But it works nicely to show how to output text using the good old print() function:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='',
        usage="""myparser [-h] print this help and exit
        """,
        formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter
    )
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--file',help='CSV input file', required=True)
  
    args = parser.parse_args()

    with open("output.file", "w") as outfile:

        with open(args.file) as csvfile:
       
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            line_count = 0
            for row in csv_reader:
                if line_count == 0:
                    line_count += 1
               elif args.archive:
                    print(f'no:{row[0]}:{row[1]}::0:0:0:/bin/bash:0:0:{row[2]}:{row[3]}:{row[4]}:archive', file=outfile)
                    line_count += 1 

return sys.exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Sorry for the indentation.

This code opens a CSV file for reading and uses the print() function to write a formatted string that will look like:

```
no:Xoero:ToelAs:xtoelas:0:0:0:/bin/bash:0:0:y.r.j.pols@tue.nl:00311234567890:nl:archive
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reading CSV with Headers to Objects List**

Example of reading CSV with headers into a list of objects, this may be more commonly needed so I provided an example below. Essentially we have a object type which we will put the data into, each user's data will go into one object containing 'name, age, startdate'. then we will populate each object and store them to a list in the order they were read from the file.

```
import csv

# We need a default object for each person 
class Person:
    def __init__(self, Name, Age, StartDate):
        self.Name = Name
        self.Age = Age
        self.StartDate = StartDate

# We read in each row and assign it to an object then add that object to the overall list, 
# and continue to do this for the whole list, and return the list
def read_csv_to_objects(file_path):
    Persons = []
    with open(file_path, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in csv_reader:
            if row['Name']:
                Each = Person(row['Name'], row['Age'], row['StartDate'])
                Persons.append(Each)
    return Persons

# Main calls the functions
file_path = "people.csv"
Persons = read_csv_to_objects(file_path)
for person in Persons:
    print(f"Name: {person.Name}   Age: {person.Age}   StartDate: {person.StartDate}")
```

**Output:**

```
python3 import_people.py
Name: Bill   Age: 21   StartDate: 10-10-2024
Name: Mike   Age: 25   StartDate: 10-11-2013
Name: Vic   Age: 44   StartDate: 9-11-2023
```

**File people.csv :**

```
Name,Age,StartDate
Bill,21,10-10-2024
Mike,25,10-11-2013
Vic,44,9-11-2023
```