# How to access csv file values in python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with columns containing pixel values as shown in the image.
I want to read/access each value, I tried using numpy.genfromtxt but cudn't access the values.

csv file snapshot

[image]

Comment: Self included question please.

Comment: What's your code and what's the error messages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read and write CSV files with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python)

Comment: Please do not upload images of textual data: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how you want to access them, the following shows how it could be done using Python's CSV library:

```
import csv

with open('corners_topsingle.csv', 'rb') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    data = []

    for row in csv_input:
        values = []
        for value in row[2:]:
            x, y = value.strip('()').split(',')
            values.append((int(x), int(y)))

        data.append(row[:2] + values)

print data
```

This would give you `data` looking like:

```
[['1', '02.jpg', (86, 54), (89, 454), (321, 76), (309, 418)], 
 ['2', '03.jpg', (86, 54), (89, 454), (321, 76), (309, 418)], 
 ['3', '04.jpg', (86, 54), (89, 454), (321, 76), (309, 418)]]
```

This assumes you are using Python 2.x and a row of your CSV file looks something like:

```
1,02.jpg,"(86,54)","(89,454)","(321,76)","(309,418)"
```

For Python 3.x, use:

```
with open('corners_topsingle.csv', 'r', newline='') as f_input:
```

and change to `print(data)`