# issue in saving string list in to text file

Tags: python-3.x, text, save

I am trying to save and read the strings which are saved in a text file.

```
a = [['str1','str2','str3'],['str4','str5','str6'],['str7','str8','str9']]
file = 'D:\\Trails\\test.txt'

# writing list to txt file
thefile = open(file,'w')
for item in a:
    thefile.write("%s\n" % item)
thefile.close()

#reading list from txt file
readfile = open(file,'r')
data = readfile.readlines()#

print(a[0][0])
print(data[0][1]) # display data read
```

the output:

```
str1
'
```

both a[0][0] and data[0][0] should have the same value, reading which i saved returns empty. What is the mistake in saving the file?

Update:

the 'a' array is having strings on different lengths. what are changes that I can make in saving the file, so that output will be the same.

Update:

I have made changes by saving the file in csv instead of text using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python), incase of text how to save the data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the list directly on file and use the *eval* function to translate the saved data on file in list again. Isn't recommendable but, the follow code works.

```
a = [['str1','str2','str3'],['str4','str5','str6'],['str7','str8','str9']]
file = 'test.txt'

# writing list to txt file
thefile = open(file,'w')
thefile.write("%s" % a)
thefile.close()

#reading list from txt file
readfile = open(file,'r')
data = eval(readfile.readline())
print(data)

print(a[0][0])
print(data[0][1]) # display data read

print(a)
print(data)
```

Comment: It is giving an error when adding eval. "TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object"

Comment: Check if this line `data = eval(readfile.readline())` is `readline()` not `readlines()`

Comment: eval not working. I am using python 3.6 does that making any difference?

Comment: @Raady I tested it with python 3.6.4 and 2.7.14 and the result are the same. `python2 bla.py                                                                                                                                       
[['str1', 'str2', 'str3'], ['str4', 'str5', 'str6'], ['str7', 'str8', 'str9']]
str1
str2`. `python3 python bla.py                                                                                                                                        
[['str1', 'str2', 'str3'], ['str4', 'str5', 'str6'], ['str7', 'str8', 'str9']]
str1
str2`

Answer (score 0):

a and data will not have same value as a is a list of three lists.
Whereas data is a list with three strings.
`readfile.readlines()` or `list(readfile)` writes all lines in a list.
So, when you perform `data = readfile.readlines()` python consider `['str1','str2','str3']\n` as a single string and not as a list.
So,to get your desired output you can use following print statement.
`print(data[0][2:6])`

Comment: This is an example, str1 and str2 in my data are not of same size. In that case how can I save the data so that the output will be same ? or else is there any other read function ?