# Train-test Split of a CSV file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science

I have a `.csv` file that contains my data. I would like to do `Logistic Regression`, `Naive Bayes` and `Decision Trees`. I already know how to implement these.

However, my teacher wants me to split the data in my `.csv` file into `80%` and let my algorithms predict the other `20%`. I would like to know how to actually split the data in that way.

```
diabetes_df = pd.read_csv("diabetes.csv")
diabetes_df.head()

with open("diabetes.csv", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read().split()
    train_data = data[:80]
    test_data = data[20:]
```

I tried to split it like this (sure it isn't working).

Comment: Mention the type of data contains in csv

Comment: Look here -> http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Comment: The file contains data to predict the outcome of diabetes based on the following features: Number of pregnancies, glucose, blood pressure, insulin, BMI,... it's all numerical data and it's labeled. There are 2 possibles outcomes (1 = have diabetes and 0 = does not have diabetes).

Comment: Do you want the 80% first lines to go into learning set and the last 20 % in the test set, or do you need/accept a more flat repartition? Anyway, that is a pure text line processing question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Workflow

1. Load the data (see [How do I read and write CSV files with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41585078/562769)
   )
2. Preprocess the data (e.g. filtering / creating new features)
3. Make the train-test (validation and dev-set) split

### Code

Sklearns [`sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) is what you are looking for:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=0)
```

Comment: Thank You so much. I think this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

```
splitted_csv = "value1,value2,value3".split(',')
print(str(splitted_csv)) #["value1", "value2", "value3"]
print(splitted_csv[0]) #value1
print(splitted_csv[1]) #value2
print(splitted_csv[2]) #value3
```

There are also libraries that parse csv and allow you to access at value by column name, but from your example i thought that you need some "low level" way to do it