# how to read rows and columns from a csv file using python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to retrieve the rows and columns of a `csv` file using python.
But I am unable to do so.
My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("data1.csv", nrows=1)
print(data)
```

This code prints the column name and the first row values.
However, I want to display only specific columns and its respective row values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read and write CSV files with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python)

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("data1.csv", nrows=1)
print(data)
```

A couple of things first:
* You have passed a kwarg`nrows=1`. This means you have only read the first row. If you take that out, you will get all the rows.

- When you use pandas, you get a `data frame`.
- Once you have the`dataframe`, you can extract the wanted columns like so:

  selected_data = data[[‘column_name1’, ‘column_name2’]]
- You can also use a more numeric column index syntax like so:

  selected_data = data.iloc[:,1:4]

Where you select all the rows `:`, and column index 1 up to butnot including 4, `1:4`