# Create CSV to put variables from Regular Expressions separated with comma python

Tags: python, regex, csv, variables

```
keywords_cap = ['SpA', 'SPA', 'LIMITADA', 'LTDA', 'S.A.']
keywords_cap = map(re.escape, keywords_cap)
keywords_cap.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
obj = re.compile(r'[:,;.]\s*"?([^:,;.]*?(?<!\w)(?:{}))'.format('|'.join(keywords_cap)))
m = obj.search(mensaje)
if m:
    company_name = ("COMPANY NAME: {}".format(m.group(1)))

regex = r"\s*CVE\s+([^|]*)"
matches = re.search(regex, mensaje)
if matches:
    company_cve = ("CVE: %s" % matches.group(1).strip())

dic = [company_name, company_cve, "example", "another"]  #dictionary

create_csv = "exampleCsv.csv" 
csv = open(create_csv, "w") 

columnTitleRow = "name, cve\n"
csv.write(columnTitleRow)

for key in dic.keys():
 company_name = key
 company_cve = dic[key]
 row = company_name + "," + company_cve + "\n"
 csv.write(row)
```

I have a lot of regular expressions inside a for. Here an example with the variable CVE found in a text file. I would like to be able to write the result of all the variables found in the text in a csv separated by commas.

INPUT: Variables company_name and company_cve (and more extracted from regular expressions...)

OUTPUT: CVE with header the name of the variables and below another row with the result of variable company_name, company_cve, and others variables.

Comment: can you add example input and desired output?

Comment: Now it is explained

Comment: Is your problem just with writing out the CSV file? If so, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read and write CSV files with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not totally clear from the problem statement, but I think you are collecting data about a company (or many companies) and then you want to print that data out in a CSV file.

Firstly, a couple of issues with your existing code:

```
dic = [company_name, company_cve, "example", "another"]  #dictionary
```

This is a list, not a dictionary. A dictionary has a key-value structure, and would be declared like this:

```
dic = { 'name': company_name, 'cve': company_cve, 'example': 'example data' }
```

Secondly, it's better to use `with` when opening a file to forestall potential file opening errors:

```
with open('exampleCsv.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    # write to the file
```

Thirdly, if you use the existing `csv` library, you don't have to worry about cases where (e.g.) company names or other file data has commas in it; `csv` will handle that for you. See the [`csv` library documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html) for full details. You will need to import the `cvs` library at the start of your script:

```
import csv
import re
```

and create a `csv.writer` object to output your data:

```
with open('exampleCsv.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"') # set your CSV options here
```

Depending on what data structure you are using to hold the company data, you can print it out in different ways.

```
# list of headers
headers = [ 'company_name', 'company_cve', 'prop_1', 'prop_2' ]

# list of variables holding company data
dic = [ company_name, company_cve, example_1, example_2 ]

with open('exampleCsv.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    writer.writerow( headers )  # print the header row
    writer.writerow( dic )
```

Or if you created a dictionary containing your company data:

```
company = {
    'company_name': 'Company A',
    'company_cve': 'Some value',
    'prop_1': 'value 1',
    'prop_2': 'value 2'
}
# note that dictionary keys match the headers
headers = [ 'company_name', 'company_cve', 'prop_1', 'prop_2' ]

with open('exampleCsv.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    writer.writerow( headers )
    writer.writerow( map( lambda x: company[x], headers ) )
```

or a list of dictionaries for many companies:

```
company_data = [{
    'company_name': 'Company A',
    'company_cve': 'Some value',
    'prop_1': 'value 1',
    'prop_2': 'value 2'
},{
    'company_name': 'Company B',
    'company_cve': 'A different value',
    'prop_1': 'value 3',
    'prop_2': 'value 4'

}]

headers = [ 'company_name', 'company_cve', 'prop_1', 'prop_2' ]

with open('exampleCsv.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    writer.writerow( headers )
    for c in company_data:
        writer.writerow( map( lambda x: c[x], headers ) )
```