# Exporting PDF metadata to a CSV

Tags: csv, parsing, pdf, export-to-csv

I have this script from my professor that prints metadata from a folder containing PDF files. I need to be able to export this data to a newly created CSV file.

I can't figure out where / what I need to do.

Here is the script for the PDF data extraction.

```py
#!/ bin/bash/ python
import csv
import os
import pyPdf
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader
print "Please enter the path containing your PDF files for analysis."
print '-' * 61
targ_dir = raw_input("Path: ")
file_names = os.listdir(targ_dir)
pdfMetadata = open('E:\CVF\Python\Python Class\PDF_metadata.csv','w')
def getPDFdata (PDFFile):
    pdf = PdfFileReader(file(PDFFile, 'rb'))
    if pdf.isEncrypted:
        pdf.decrypt('')
    metadata = pdf.getDocumentInfo()
print PDFFile
for info in metadata:
        try:
            print info+"::"+metadata[info]
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            print "BAD CHARACTER ERROR"
    print "__________________________________________"
for item in file_names:
    getPDFdata(targ_dir+"\\"+item)
end = raw_input("Press Enter to Finish: ")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read and write CSV files with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python)