# How to read CSV File and add each cell in a row to a list?

Tags: python, csv

I have an CSV file which looks like this:

```
104 109 113 111 108 114
95  100 109 103 103 110
```

Two rows, and every number has its own cell.

How do i read the CSV file per row and add each cell of that row to a list?

The output should look like this:

```
List_1 = [104, 109, 113, 111, 108, 114]
List_2 = [95, 100, 109, 103, 103, 110]
```

Also i need the numbers in the list as integer not as a string.

Comment: So you only have two rows?

Comment: At the Moment, yes! But there will be more in the future.

Comment: So you want to put all rows in lists? I think is better if you expand a little on what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps you could use pandas.

Comment: At the Moment i have two rows with temperatures. High and Low. I Need those in two lists (at the moment). I never worked with Pandas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read and write CSV files with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python)

Comment: And ? What's your question exactly ? So far you explained what you wanted to do but didn't ask any question.

Comment: I updated my question. I hope ist okay like that. My question was answered. I think my question and the answere are clear to Show what i want to achive!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just store each row in a dictionary:

```
d = {}
with open('rows.csv') as f:
    for row, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
        d['Line_%d' % row] = list(map(int, line.split()))

print(d)
# {'Line_1': [104, 109, 113, 111, 108, 114], 'Line_2': [95, 100, 109, 103, 103, 110]}
```

Then you can access each row like this:

```
>>> d['Line_1']
[104, 109, 113, 111, 108, 114]
>>> d['Line_2']
[95, 100, 109, 103, 103, 110]
```

**UPDATE:**

As requested in the comments, if you file has a semicolon `;` as a delimiter, you can use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) library:

```
from csv import reader

d = {}
with open('rows.csv') as f:
    csv_reader = reader(f, delimiter=';')
    for i, line in enumerate(csv_reader, start=1):
        d['Line_%d' % i] = list(map(int, line))

print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `map` to transform list of string to list of ints and append in the output list

```
final=[]
with open('test.csv') as f:
    for row in f:
        final.append(list(map(int,row)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` `read_csv` function for reading CSV file. Afterwards you will have a `DataFrame` object. Using `df.values.tolist()` you will get the list of all rows as lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
my.csv:    
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 0
```

Python:

```
with open("my.csv") as f:
    lists = [ list(map(int, i.split())) for i in f.readlines() ]

print(lists[0])
print(lists[1])
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  
[6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would want to make later mathematical operations on your data, you might consider using `numpy` module for that, you can use `numpy.loadtxt` function (remember that `csv` files are in fact plain text files).
Usage example:
`test.csv` is file I created, it contain 2 rows each with 3 values

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Then you can create numpy array following way:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.load('test.csv',int,delimiter=' ')
```

`test.csv` is name of file, `int` is information that you wants integers and `delimiter=' '` means that values in file are space-separated. You can access values in numpy array by giving index of row and index of element

```
print(data[0][0]) #prints 1
print(data[1][2]) #prints 6
```

If you want to get `list` of values simply pass `data[index_of_row]` into `list()`

```
list1 = list(data[0])
list2 = list(data[1])
print(list1) #prints [1, 2, 3]
print(list2) #prints [4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also solve it this way instead, using the csv.reader() module.

```
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)

    list_ = []

    for row in reader:
        list_.append(row)
```

To access the first line (line_1 in the example)`line_1 = list_[0]`