# how to write and append loop output in a csv file using python

Tags: python, file, csv, file-io

I want to store elements in a csv file using loops, for example,

```
  for i in range(0,10):
      #I want to append each i values in new rows of that csv file.
```

The output final csv file with look like,

```
   0       
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   7 
   8
   9
```

How to do it in efficient way ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read and write CSV files with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import csv
with open('loop.csv','w') as f1:
    writer=csv.writer(f1, delimiter='\t',lineterminator='\n',)
    for i in range(0,10):
       row = [i]
       writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using 'a' not 'w'?

Answer (score 5):

There are some oddities with the code above, notably that "w" option will overwrite the csv file. from my test this would actually append to an already existing file.

```
import csv
with open(r'loop.csv','a') as f1: # need "a" and not w to append to a file, if not will overwrite
    writer=csv.writer(f1, delimiter='\t',lineterminator='\n',)
    # two options here, either:
    for i in range(0,10):
       row = [i]
       writer.writerow(row)
    #OR
    writer.writerows([i for i in range(10)]) #note that range(0,10) and range(10) are the same thing
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for each number `i` write the number to the file:

```
import csv
with open("filename.csv", 'w') as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  for i in range(10):
      writer.writerow(iter(i))
```

For your case this could be simply put this way as well.

```
import csv
with open("filename.csv", 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    f.writerows(map(str, range(10)))
```