# How do i make a sublist of every CSV row and put that sublist inside a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv, sublist

I'm making a sublist of every row inside a csv file but i'm getting a single list back

```
wines_list = []

for row in wines:
    wines_list.append(row)

print(wines_list)
```

This returns:

```
['id', 'country', 'description', 'designation', 'points', 'price', 
'province', 'taster_name', 'title', 'variety', 'winery', 'fixed acidity', 
'volatile acidity', 'citric acid', 'residual sugar', 'chlorides', 'free 
sulfur dioxide', 'total sulfur dioxide', 'density', 'pH', 'sulphates', 
'alcohol']
```

But i wan't it to append all values to sublist, and append that to wines_list

So i want wines_list to become something like:

```
[[1, 'netherlands', 'description of the wine', 'designation', 'points', 'price', 
'province', 'taster_name', 'title', 'variety', 'winery', 'fixed acidity', 
'volatile acidity', 'citric acid', 'residual sugar', 'chlorides', 'free 
sulfur dioxide', 'total sulfur dioxide', 'density', 'pH', 'sulphates', 
'alcohol'], ANOTHER SUB LIST HERE]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easiest way is something like this

```
import csv
pathtocsv='path/to/file'
with open(pathtocsv,'r') as cfile:
    creader=csv.reader(cfile,delimiter=',')
    wines_list=list(creader)

print(wines_list)
```

then `wines_list` will be a list of lists

Comment: if you don't want the headers, sure you could. or `wines_list.pop(0)` at the end of the `with` block

Comment: Thank you! got it to work, will accept as soon as i can!