# Using pandas to read values of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to use pandas read an append list and show each column, but it read each list as a column

```
li= []
for k in sample:
    lines = open(k).read().splitlines()
    for i in range(num):
       lines = random.choice(lines)
       lines = lines.replace('\t',' ')
       li.append(lines)   
       data = DataFrame(li)
```

'''

where the sample is a serious of files, and the result looks like:

```
                0
0 1.0 1.0 1.0 ...
1 1.0 1.0 1.0 ...
.
.
.
```

but I would like it as:

```
    0    1   2 ...
0  1.0 1.0 1.0 ...
1  1.0 ...
.
.
.
```

Comment: split the lines on separators. Look at any similar question that works off of csvs, yours is a csv with just a different separator (tab or space delimited).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read and write CSV files with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you have either TSV or a space delimited files. Pandas can read that directly be choosing the appropriate `sep` argument.

If those are tabs between the cells it would look like:
`pandas.read_csv(‘your/file/path.txt’, sep=‘\t’)`

For spaces set `sep` to `sep=‘ ‘`

To read multiple files, you would do this and then append or concat the Dataframes together.