# Reading a CSV file when rows are split onto multiple lines

Tags: python, csv

This is my code to read my data from a CSV file row by row:

```
filepath = 'dataset-CalheirosMoroRita-2017.csv'
   with open(filepath) as fp:
   line = fp.readline()
   cnt = 1
while line:
   print("syntax {}: {}".format(cnt, line.strip())) 
   line = fp.readline()
   cnt += 1
```

**I am trying to taking rows of CSV file as an input(string)type**
for my function

```
def members(dictArg, new_list,length_of_string):
  total=0

  for list_item in new_list:
      for letter, number in dictArg.items():

          if list_item==letter:

            print(letter)
            total= total+number
            print(total)

  return ((total/length_of_string)*100)
```

I don't know how to get multiple rows one by one in new_list, **new_list is the argument which take input from csv file** but this is confusing me how to get input from csv ***by using for loop*** .

Comment: The indentation in your first snippet is wrong. You can [edit] to fix it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read and write CSV files with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python)

Comment: BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask]

Comment: It would help us if you [edit] your question to show a short (5 line text) sample of your CSV file and the output you are trying to get for it.

Comment: That dataset looks like hotel reviews?

Answer (score 0):

The dataset that you are trying to parse appears to have [hotel reviews](https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/9kgd88vrbr/1/files/2da07d55-3971-4485-8090-8993ff5f8309). This file as you have seen, sometimes has one review split onto a number of lines. In this case, the review is enclosed in double quotes.

Python's CSV library can actually handle this automatically. As there is only one review per line, the `csv.reader()` delimiter can be changed to `delimiter='\n'`. The data though also contains a lot of whitespace which can also be removed using the `strip()` function.

For example, a list of all of the reviews could be created at follows:

```
import csv

reviews = []

with open('dataset-CalheirosMoroRita-2017.csv') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='\n')
    header = next(csv_input)
    
    for row in csv_input:
        entry = [value.strip() for value in row if len(value.strip())]
        reviews.append(''.join(entry))
```

So the first 3 reviews could be displayed with `print(reviews[:3])` giving:

```
['Everything from the weather, staff, food, property, fire pits, décor, spa, rooms and beach were top notch', 'The hotel it is fantastic built by the sea, living together with nature. Environment it is great as well as people and service.\nWe full enjoyed the place, and facilities.\nThanks for the "cidreira" and "madalenas" tea at reception', 'One dream! Cozy  and comfortable Hotel!  The best personalized one! All the employees are congratulated! Very nice taste, since reception to the end of the stay! We were welcome with tea and cake, as I have gluten aversion,, all the employees already knew and were waiting carefully. At night, we were received in the fire pits, with some wine and all the guests were invited to participate and interact.']
```