# How to split lines in python

Tags: python

I am looking for a simple way to split lines in python from a .txt file and then just read out the names and compare them to another file.

I've had a code that split the lines successfully, but I couldn't find a way to read out just the names, unfortunately the code that split it successfully was lost.

this is what the .txt file looks like.

```
Id;Name;Job;
1;James;IT;
2;Adam;Director;
3;Clare;Assisiant;
```

example if the code I currently have (doesn't output anything)

```
my_file = open("HP_liki.txt","r")
flag = index = 0 
x1=""
for line in my_file: 
    line.strip().split('\n') 
    index+=1 
content = my_file.read()
list=[]
lines_to_read = [index-1]
for position, line1 in enumerate(x1):
    if position in lines_to_read:
        list=line1
        x1=list.split(";")
    print(x1[1])
```

I need a solution that doesn't import `pandas` or `csv`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read and write CSV files with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python)

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your code confuses me as to your purpose.

```
for line in my_file: 
    line.strip().split('\n') 
    index+=1 
content = my_file.read()
```

Your `for` loop iterates through the file and strips each line.  Then it splits on a newline, *which cannot exist* at this point.  The `for` already iterates by lines, so there is no newline in any `line` in this loop.

In addition, once you've stripped the line, you ignore the result, increment `index`, and leave the loop.  As a result, all this loop accomplishes is to count the lines in the file.

The line after the loop reads from a file that has no more data, so it will simply handle the EOF exception and return nothing.

---

If you want the names from the file, then use the built-in file read to iterate through the file, split each line, and extract the second field:

```
name_list = [line.split(';')[1]
               for line in open("HP_liki.txt","r") ]
```

`name_list` also includes the header `"Name"`, which you can easily delete.

Does that handle your problem?

Answer (score 1):

So without using any external library you can use simple file io and then generalize according to your need.

**readfile.py**

```
file = open('datafile.txt','r')

for line in file:
    line_split = line.split(';')
    if (line_split[0].isdigit()):
        print(line_split[1])

file.close()
```

**datafile.txt**

```
Id;Name;Job;
1;James;IT;
2;Adam;Director;
3;Clare;Assisiant;
```

If you run this you'll have output

```
James
Adam
Clare
```

You can change the `if` condition according to your need

Answer (score 0):

I have my dataf.txt file:

```
Id;Name;Job;
1;James;IT;
2;Adam;Director;
3;Clare;Assisiant;
```

I have written this to extract information:

```
with open('dataf.txt','r') as fl:
    data = fl.readlines()
    a = [i.replace('\n','').split(';')[:-1] for i in data]
    print(a[1:])
```

Outputs:

```
[['1', 'James', 'IT'], ['2', 'Adam', 'Director'], ['3', 'Clare', 'Assisiant']]
```