# writing in csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, python-3.8

It's the first time I want to write in a CSV file and there are some strings I want to write as output.
I used 'writerow' function but it writes them in list type while I simply want them to be strings
has anyone have any idea what should I do?

my code:

```
with open (r'C:\Users\part pardaz\Desktop\out_put.csv' , mode='w' , newline='' ) as ff : 
    mean_writer=csv.writer(ff)
    for  item in (names):
    print(item)      
    my_row=[item + ',' + means[item] ]
    print(my_row)
    mean_writer.writerow((my_row))
```

I want my output to be like this:

jack,23

mike,76

but it's like this:

[jack,23]

[mike,76]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read and write CSV files with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python)

Comment: Normally `my_row` would be a list of values, with each element in the list corresponding to a cell.  Your list appears to contain a single string with a comma in it.  Is that really what you want?  As opposed to `my_row = [item, means[item]]`?

Comment: You left out crucial details. What are `names` and `means`? And yank that line `mean_writer=csv.writer(ff)` out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple things wrong with the code, please put csv.writer out of your for loop.

Try this code below before you try yours.

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

Also try replacing:

```
mean_writer.writerow((my_row))
```

with

```
mean_writer.writerow(my_row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas library, and then just make use of pandas `read_csv` and `to_csv` functions. Something like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('path/to/csv')
# do some stuff with the loaded csv
df.to_csv('path/to/csv')
```