# How can I read a text file and only print specific lines where the value in one column is above a threshold?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to read a comma-separated text file that looks like this:

```
ID, x, y, soil_temp
1, 10, 6, 8
2, 21, 11, 12
3, 11, 7, 7
4, 32, 12, 8
5, 9, 29, 6
6, 17, 16, 9
7, 22, 9, 11
8, 14, 31, 7
9, 26, 21, 6
10, 19, 19, 10
```

And thereafter I have to print the columns ID and soil_temp and all the lines with soil temperature above 10. So the result should look something like this:

```
ID, soil_temp
2, 12
7, 11
```

Important! No modules should be needed such as pandas and cv, which makes the exercise frustrating for me. It is probably quite easy for most people here.

So I have made a code that looks like this to be able to print the column with `soil_temp`:

```
tempLine = []
with open('soil_temp.txt', 'r') as f:
    read_data = f.readlines()

for line in read_data:
    line.split()
    tempLine.append(line.split())

for item in tempLine:
    print(item[3])
```

This code is also based on advices given in the exercise. My problem is that if I want to only print the lines above 10, I would think a simple `if` statement in the last part of the code, something like this would make sense:

```
for item in tempLine:
    if item[3] > 10
        print(item[3])
```

But of course this does not work since the data is stored as strings. I have tried different solutions to change them into integers but since it is multiple strings, I can't find a solution.

Comment: Tips: `line.split(",")` # split on commas, then perhaps s.strip() to remove whitespace, then int(s) to cast a string to an integer.

Comment: Does this naswer your question? [How do I read and write CSV files with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python)

Comment: Why are you using a txt file instead of CSV?

Comment: Hi there, pandas DataFrame might give a more concise solution:
```import pandas as pd; pd.read_csv('soil_temp.txt'); df[df[' soil_temp']>10][['ID', ' soil_temp']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might do it like this:

```
with open('soil_temp.txt', 'r') as f:
    read_data = f.readlines()[1:]

id_and_temp = [(i, t)
    for i, _, _, t in (line.strip().split(", ") for line in read_data)
    if int(t) > 10
]

print("ID, soil_temp")
for i, t in id_and_temp:
    print(f"{i}, {t}")
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you have to split on comma.  I have reworked your code a bit, and used a list comprehension to make `tempLine` be a list of lists containg the row-data.

```py
with open('soil_temp.txt', 'r') as f:
    f.readline() # get rid of header line
    read_data = f.readlines()

tempLine = []
for line in read_data:
    tempLine.append([int(x) for x in line.split(',')]) # make a list of ints out of each dataline

print(tempLine) # to show the structure

for item in tempLine:
    if item[3] > 10:
        print(item[3])
```

The output from running it will is as follows:

```
[[1, 10, 6, 8], [2, 21, 11, 12], [3, 11, 7, 7], [4, 32, 12, 8], [5, 9, 29, 6], [6, 17, 16, 9], [7, 22, 9, 11], [8, 14, 31, 7], [9, 26, 21, 6], [10, 19, 19, 10]]
12
11
```

This is not idiomatic Python; I wanted to show how to change your existing code to get over your bump.