# How to separate a string in a csv file into multiple cells on each semicolon using python

Tags: python, csv

I have data in this format, which is stored in a csv file:
3;6/3/2021;B;12/06/2021;BNP FP E;P;12;12;CONDORI;12;9:55:29;ETF;MINE;

I would like to separate this string into new cells of a each row on every semicolon detected in the same csv file.

Current code:

```
import sys, psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=name user=userpassword=password")
cur = conn.cursor()

sql = "COPY (SELECT * FROM trades WHERE \"DATE_TRADE\" = '6/3/2021') TO STDOUT WITH CSV DELIMITER ';'"
with open(r'Y:\RESULT.csv', "a+") as file:
    cur.copy_expert(sql, file)
    array = file.readlines()
    array = [row.split(';') for row in array]
```

Yields a file that has all the records but not separated on each semi-colon

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Why do you not use the csv module from the standard library?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read and write CSV files with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python)

Comment: But more importantly, why do you not read the data from the database directly into your program, instead of writing it to a CSV file and reading it again?

Comment: `cur.execute('SELECT ...').fetchall()` should be enough...

Answer (score -1):

```
with open("data.csv") as file:
    contents = file.read().split("\n")
array = [c.split(";") for c in contents]
```

Comment: Please do not blindly advise to use `split` to parse an arbitrary csv file, when the CSV module is much more robust and cares for separators or new lines inside fields.