# Writing webscrapped data into CSV

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

With the below code I am able to scrape product infromation from two websites. My goal is to write the scraped data into a CSV where column A is used for the class "label" and column B is used for the class "value"

Can anyone help me achieve the desired outcome?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url_list = ["https://21shares.com/product/abtc", "https://21shares.com/product/aeth/"]


for link in url_list:
    r = requests.get(link)
    r.encoding = 'uft-8'
    html_content = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
    datas = soup.find('div', {'class':'product-sidebar-container'})

    for data in datas:
        soup.findAll("span", {"class": "Label", "Value": True})
        print(data.getText(separator=("\n")))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read and write CSV files with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python)

Comment: @esqew thanks for the reference, I am pretty new to coding therefore I do not quite understand how I need to write the code for pandas in order to export it to a CSV in the way I would like to have it. Could you perhaps show me how it is done with the data I have scraped via my code?

Comment: There are plenty of answers in the linked duplicate that illustrate how to write Python data structures to a CSV format without the added complexity of something like Pandas - can you elaborate as to what *specifically* about the answers in the linked duplicate are not clear to you? Unfortunately Stack Overflow isn't a place you can have your code written *for* you - if you don't know where to begin or have any idea on where to start in your attempt, you might benefit from taking a step back and seeking out more foundational materials to sharpen your fundamental Python skills before continuing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize an empty list and as you iterate through `datas`, create a dictionary to append to the list. Once you have that list, it's easy to convert to a dataframe and write to csv with `pandas`. Follow the example below which is your code modified.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url_list = ["https://21shares.com/product/abtc", "https://21shares.com/product/aeth/"]

rows = []
for link in url_list:
    r = requests.get(link)
    r.encoding = 'uft-8'
    html_content = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
    datas = soup.find('div', {'class':'product-sidebar-container'})

    for data in datas:
        for each in soup.findAll("span", {"class": "label"}):
            label = each.text
            value = each.find_next('span', {'class':'value'}).text
            
            row = {'label':label, 'value':value}
            rows.append(row)


df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score -2):

You have a typo, should be 'utf-8'.

Comment: Please provide more details. The question already contains `uft-8`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).