# Unexpected result in csv file looping

Tags: python, csv, data-science

Here is my task:

Import the Python csv module.

Create a Python file object in read mode for crime_sampler.csv called csvfile.

Create an empty list called crime_data.

Loop over a csv reader on the file object :

Inside the loop, append the date (first element), type of crime (third element),
location description (fifth element),
and arrest (sixth element) to the crime_data list.

Remove the first element (headers) from the crime_data list.

Print the first 10 records of the crime_data list. This has been done for you!

```
# Import the csv module
import csv

# Create the file object: csvfile
csvfile = open('crime_sampler.csv')

# Create an empty list: crime_data
crime_data = []

# Loop over a csv reader on the file object
for row in csvfile:

    # Append the date, type of crime, location description, and arrest
    crime_data.append((row[0], row[2], row[4], row[5]))

# Remove the first element from crime_data
crime_data.pop(0)

# Print the first 10 records
print(crime_data[:10])
```

I get unexpected result, i dont know where i'm making a mistake

expected result - [('05/23/2016 05:35:00 PM', 'ASSAULT', 'STREET', 'false'), ('03/26/2016 08:20:00 PM', 'BURGLARY', 'SMALL RETAIL STORE', 'false'), ('04/25/2016 03:05:00 PM', 'THEFT', 'DEPARTMENT STORE', 'true'), ('04/26/2016 05:30:00 PM', 'BATTERY', 'SIDEWALK', 'false'), ('06/19/2016 01:15:00 AM', 'BATTERY', 'SIDEWALK', 'false'), ('05/28/2016 08:00:00 PM', 'BATTERY', 'GAS STATION', 'false'), ('07/03/2016 03:43:00 PM', 'THEFT', 'OTHER', 'false'), ('06/11/2016 06:55:00 PM', 'PUBLIC PEACE VIOLATION', 'STREET', 'true'), ('10/04/2016 10:20:00 AM', 'BATTERY', 'STREET', 'true'), ('02/14/2017 09:00:00 PM', 'CRIMINAL DAMAGE', 'PARK PROPERTY', 'false')]

my result - [('0', '/', '3', '/'), ('0', '/', '6', '/'), ('0', '/', '5', '/'), ('0', '/', '6', '/'), ('0', '/', '9', '/'), ('0', '/', '8', '/'), ('0', '/', '3', '/'), ('0', '/', '1', '/'), ('1', '/', '4', '/'), ('0', '/', '4', '/')]

DATASET

Date,Block,Primary Type,Description,Location Description,Arrest,Domestic,District
05/23/2016 05:35:00 PM,024XX W DIVISION ST,ASSAULT,SIMPLE,STREET,false,true,14
03/26/2016 08:20:00 PM,019XX W HOWARD ST,BURGLARY,FORCIBLE ENTRY,SMALL RETAIL STORE,false,false,24
04/25/2016 03:05:00 PM,001XX W 79TH ST,THEFT,RETAIL THEFT,DEPARTMENT STORE,true,false,6
04/26/2016 05:30:00 PM,010XX N PINE AVE,BATTERY,SIMPLE,SIDEWALK,false,false,15
06/19/2016 01:15:00 AM,027XX W AUGUSTA BLVD,BATTERY,AGGRAVATED: HANDGUN,SIDEWALK,false,false,12
05/28/2016 08:00:00 PM,070XX S ASHLAND AVE,BATTERY,DOMESTIC BATTERY SIMPLE,GAS STATION,false,true,7
07/03/2016 03:43:00 PM,0000X N STATE ST,THEFT,RETAIL THEFT,OTHER,false,false,1
06/11/2016 06:55:00 PM,044XX W MAYPOLE AVE,PUBLIC PEACE VIOLATION,RECKLESS CONDUCT,STREET,true,false,11
10/04/2016 10:20:00 AM,016XX W 63RD ST,BATTERY,SIMPLE,STREET,true,false,7
02/14/2017 09:00:00 PM,018XX S WOOD ST,CRIMINAL DAMAGE,TO CITY OF CHICAGO PROPERTY,PARK PROPERTY,false,false,12

Comment: Can you add the specific error you are receiving pasted directly from the error output? It does not look like you are using the csv lib you are importing?

Comment: my result [('0', '/', '3', '/'), ('0', '/', '6', '/'), ('0', '/', '5', '/'), ('0', '/', '6', '/'), ('0', '/', '9', '/'), ('0', '/', '8', '/'), ('0', '/', '3', '/'), ('0', '/', '1', '/'), ('1', '/', '4', '/'), ('0', '/', '4', '/')]

Comment: edited in question

Comment: @Mr.Proper, don't know what's inside your csv file, but you are definetely not using `csv` module. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python) you can find how you should do it

Comment: How i'm not using it? I imported it as it's said in task.

Comment: To clarify the issue, you appear to be accessing 0, 2, 4, and 5 indices of the string values for each `row`, which is why the corresponding digits and `/` from the date at the start of each `row` are printed in your result.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your csv data is not formatted properly with quotes around each field, the date field probably is unquoted based on your export. Using the proper `csv.reader` object will mitigate formatting issues.

I would properly use the csv reader that you import as a lib:

```
csvfile = csv.reader(open('crime_sampler.csv', 'r'), delimiter=',')
crime_data = []

# Loop over a csv reader on the file object
for row in csvfile:
    print(row)
    # Append the date, type of crime, location description, and arrest
    crime_data.append((row[0], row[2], row[4], row[5]))

# Remove the first element from crime_data
crime_data.pop(0)

# Print the first 10 records
print(crime_data[:10])
```

That should work. Without seeing your source data file I cannot know for sure.