# Python - Reading data from CSV to a dictionary list

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

(new to python here) I'm creating a simple contacts list program in python that loads and saves the list-dict to a csv file. The program should load the data on the csv to the list-dict (when it is launched) and rewrite the data (the list-dict) to the csv when the program is closed. Is there a way to read/load all the data from the csv file at once to the list-dict as the  "writer.writerows(list-dict)" exists for saving the data?

def load (contacts):

```
with open(list,"r") as myFile:
    a = contacts
    a = myFile.read()
    print(a)
```

By the way, this is the outpout that I am getting:(for some reason, it seems that 'a' - that was supposed to be a list-dict - is not a list-dict)
index,nome
1,asdf
2,qwer
3,xcv
4,ttt

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what about `myFile.readlines()`?

Comment: I've tried it. But i coudn't put it into the list of dicts. the code looks like this now:

    with open("/home/x/Documents/Python/Agenda","r") as myFile:
        csvReader = csv.reader(myFile)
        for row in csvReader:
            agenda['index'].append(row[0])
            agenda['nome'].append(row[1])

Comment: Using pandas might help, refer to using pandas on list of dicts in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: thanks by the help, but it still seems too dificult to me to understand...

Comment: 1) This is really something for a database. I would recommend the [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3) module that is part of the Python  global modules. 2) This does not need Pandas, that is overkill. 3) Look at my answer here [DictReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73612757/how-to-add-headers-to-read-output-from-python-csv-file/73613277#73613277) for how to use the Python [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am still stuck here: in the file, I already have 2 entries: 1,ttt and
2,hhh. However I am still getting {'1': '2', 'ttt': 'hhh'} by my code:with open("/home/tloet/Documents/Python/Agenda","r") as meuArquivo:
        reader = csv.DictReader(meuArquivo,delimiter=",", quotechar='"')
        for row in reader:
            print(dict(row))
            agenda.append(dict(row))
the right output would be: {'index': 1, 'nome': 'ttt'}