# How to get IP addresses from ip2location database?

Tags: python, download, ip, ip2location

I have downloaded IP2Proxy™ LITE database in csv format, below is the data in it

[image]

could anybody please help me how to read the ip addresses using python or powershell as it seems in plain number. Also please explain what does 1st to column represents.

Comment: is your question: how to read a csv in python?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python

Comment: https://lite.ip2location.com/faqs

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki No it's about the 1st and 2nd column in image if they represent ip then how to convert them from correct format e.g. 10.10.10.10

Comment: @NaveenKumar Did you read the FAQ? It explains how you convert those values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can convert those values into a string representation of an IPv4 address:

```
def convert(ip):
        def _genip(n):
            for shift in range(24, -8, -8):
                yield f'{(n >> shift) & 0xff:03d}'
        return '.'.join(list(_genip(int(ip))))
print(convert('34676992'))
```

**Output:**

```
002.017.033.000
```

Comment: Thanks @Cobra just want to know what 1st and 2nd column represents, as it seems both are ip's

Comment: I am using 

`$number = 2147483648
$w = [int]($number/16777216)%256
$x = [int]($number/65536)%256
$y = [int]($number/256)%256
$z = [int]$number%256
$ipAddress = "$w.$x.$y.$z"`

But getting **Cannot convert value "2147483648" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32."**

Comment: @NaveenKumar Your question is tagged for Python. The INT32 limitation is nothing to do with Python