# Python/Locust and csv-file with parameters

Tags: python, locust

Today I have hard-coded the values used in this Locust test into the script (TSIDs).
How can I, instead, feed the values from a .csv file into the script?

```
from locust import HttpUser, between, task
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

server_name = "https://xxx"

TSIDs = {'128132','85624'}

def set_from_date():
  <to be implemented>
  return from_date


def set_to_date():
  <to be implemented>
  return to_date

class LoadValues(HttpUser):
  host = server_name

  def _run_read_ts(self, series_list, resolution, start, end):
      TSIDs = ",".join(series_list)
      resp = self.client.get(f'/api/loadValues?tsIds={TSIDs}&resolution= 
      {resolution}'f'&startUtc={set_from_date()}&endUtc{set_to_date()}',
                           headers={'X-API-KEY': 'AKjCg9hTcYQ='})

      print("Response status code:", resp.status_code)

@task(1)
  def test_get_ts_1(self):
      self._run_read_ts(random.sample(TSIDs, 1), 'PT15M', 
      set_from_date(), set_to_date())
```

In other tools I have used the is a possiblity to use a feeder-class and refer to a .csv file sitting on the same place as the script.

Comment: Done @СергейКох

Answer (score 1):

Locust doesn't have anything like that built in, but it does run just about any gevent-compatible Python code so it should be simple enough to do yourself. Here's an SO question that should help you with that.

[How do I read and write CSV files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files)

That should help you populate your TSIDs. If you're running locally or with just a single instance, then you're done. If you are running in distributed mode with workers and you need the data on each to be unique, you'd need to use some method of partitioning the work for each worker. One way to do that would be to have the master [send a message to the workers](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-distributed.html#communicating-across-nodes) with the data for each using [the send_message event](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#locust.runners.MasterRunner.send_message).

If that doesn't quite work for you, some people move to a database server to query the data instead of local file. It's more setup and more advanced but opens up additional possibilities.